# Set value/text of a <span> element using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am developing a stopwatch application in an attempt to learn the Dojo Toolkit. So, to start with, I need to set the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0.

I tried:

```
dojo.byId("hours").value = "00";
```

Also tried:

```
domAttr.set("hours", 00);
```

It didnt work. In the console, the following error is thrown:

```
GET http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0 500 (Internal Server Error) moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3146
```

[Here is my fiddle so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/P7b9S/)

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `value` is only used when working with form fields. If you want to replace the actual content of the DOM node, you use `innerHTML` or `textContent` in stead. For example:

```
dojo.byId("hours").innerHTML = "00";
dojo.byId("hours").textContent = "00";
```

or

```
domAttr.set("hours", "innerHTML", "00");
domAttr.set("hours", "textContent", "00");
```

The difference between `innerHTML` and `textContent` is that the latter only allows text content (like the property says), while `innerHTML` also allows to input HTML. If you don't trust the input, you should definitely be using `textContent`.

**Be aware**: you need to put quotes around the `00` because else it will be interpreted as a numeric value, which means the first `0` is skipped when you output it.

I also changed your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/P7b9S/1/).

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. But the error still persists. Any idea why?

Comment: That error is unrelated to your code, it's actually an error of JSFiddle, not you ;)

Comment: oh! Thanks though. Accepting your answer in 3 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert **text** (not HTML) and don't want to worry about carefully escaping problem-characters like `<`, consider:

```
dojo.byId("hours").textContent = "00";
```

This works everywhere except IE8 and below, and unlike `innerHtml` it should be safe for problematic text like "a

```
dojo.byId("hours").innerText = "00";
```

You can see more about compatibility at [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html).

> In the console, the following error is thrown:

That error refers to network communication, which your code isn't doing. It's probably spurious, something particular to JSFiddle, especially considering the text `jobofferinsidebar` which sounds like an ad.